# Android - when increasing price of an app, does it cost people money to upgrade?

Tags: android

Sorry, I know this is not a programming question, but I just had no idea where else to ask.

Where would I find out this information?

Thanks!

Comment: You're 100% spot on, it isn't a programming question

Comment: No, it doesn't cost. But should be asked here: http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks guys, I will close the question. -4 :) Ouch :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update a purchased App is free.